# Failure rate in Weibull distribution

Tags: distribution, exponential, weibull

I use well known parameter estimation methods to estimate `scale` and `shape` parameters the Weibull. By the end I have a good estimation `reliability function`.

I have `failure rate` that change over time of my items. Can I use the `failure rate as shape or scale` parameter in my weibull function.

I tried to use the `failure rate` instead of the `shape`, and I still have good `reliability function`.

Many articles use failure rate as `λ` the rate parameter in exponential distribution

Comment: Can you edit to show the programming implementation aspect of the question? Or would it be better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: It is just theoretical question, should I delete it